# Polynomials and Modular Arithmetic: Elementary Number Theory Problem

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $f(x)$ be a non-constant polynomial with integer coefficients. Let $a, k$, and $m$ be integers with $m > 1.$ Suppose that $f(a) ≡ k$ $\pmod  m.$ Prove that $f(a + m) ≡ k$ $\pmod  m.$

I've fiddled around, expanding $f(a + m)$, factoring etc., and am looking at $f(a + m) - f(a)$, but can't quite get it right.

Comment: Do you know Taylor's formula?

Comment: um yeah, like Taylor series? But I don't have a deep knowledge so simpler is better.

Comment: $(a+m)^n = a^n + n a^{n-1} m+\cdots +m^n \equiv a^n \pmod m \implies \sum_\limits {i=0}^n y_i (a+m)^i \equiv \sum_\limits {i=0}^n y_i a^i \pmod m$

Comment: Does anyone know how to do this without Taylor's formula?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $(a+m)^n = a^n+\sum_{i=1}^nca^{n-i}m^i\equiv a^n $ mod $m$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove it  only on the monomial $x^r$

$(x+m)^r≡\sum_{i=0}^r\binom rix^{r-i}m^i≡x^r  mod(m)$.

Answer (score 0):

For a polynomial of degree $d$, *Taylor's formula*  at order $d$ is an exact formula, i.e.
$$f(a+x)=f(a) +f'(a) x+\dots +\frac{f^{(d)}(a)}{d!} x^n.$$
In particular:
  \begin{align}f(a+m)&=f(a) +f'(a) m+\dots +\frac{f^{(d)}(a)}{d!} m^d \\
&=f(a) +m\Bigl(f'(a) +\dots +\frac{f^{(d)}(a)}{d!} m^{d-1}\Bigr)\\
&\equiv f(a)\mod m.
\end{align}

Comment: In this case $\frac{f^{(d)}(a)}{d!}m^{d-1}$ must be an integer

Comment: Well, it *is* an integer!

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: How do you prove that it's an integer ? Maybe someone has down voted because it's $x^d$ instead of $x^n$.

Comment: I didn't know the degree was normalised to $n$… It's fairly obvious it's an integer: we start from a polynomial with integer coefficients, so $f(a+x)$ also has integer coefficients, and these coefficients are unique.

Comment: Indeed I forgot the condition on the coefficients...